# How to make Midnight Commander open file with default application in Windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-terminal, mc

I recently started using Midnight Commander on my Windows 10 system, but I can't seem to get it to handle images or pdf files properly. When I select the file and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens. I've tried altering the extension file to the following.

```
default/*
    Open=(%f)
```

After making that change, I get this error.

```
C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Temp/mc-MyUser/mcext2509Z1: line 13: C:/Test.txt: Permission denied
```

I am using the Powershell v7.3.2 in Windows Terminal v1.15.3465.0 on Windows 10 v.19044.2486

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
default/*
    Open=start %f
```

Try `start C:\Test.txt` from the `cmd` command line to test.

See https://superuser.com/q/550138. Try

```
start "" %f
```

For Powershell try

```
Start-Process %f
```

Comment: When trying either of those methods I get the following error:
/bin/sh C:/Users/myUser/AppData/Local/Temp/mc-myUser/mcextI179Z1
C:/Users/myUser/AppData/Local/Temp/mc-myUser/mcextI179Z1: line 13: start: not found

Comment: `/bin/sh`?!!! Is it WSL or git-bash? For WSL use `wslview`; see https://superuser.com/a/1600972 . Found in https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=wsl+open+file+with+default+application

Comment: And of course there is always `cmd /c "start %f"` or `cmd /k "start %f"`

Comment: `cmd /c %f` did the trick. I think you're on to something with `/bin/sh`. It looks like when you launch `mc` in a Powershell window, it's running in a virtual console.